# Django slug two in one confusion

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to display a blog as follows:

1. domain.com/blog/category/categoryA
2. domain.com/blog/category/categoryA/post-one

At the moment (1) works successfully, and (2) works partially, so it displays like:

domain.com/blog/post-one

**How can I set post category - posts that belong to that category before display post slug?**

My urls.py:

```
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.list_of_post_by_category, name='list_of_post_by_category'),
```

My views.py

```
def list_of_post_by_category(request,category_slug):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    post = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        post = post.filter(category=category)
    template = 'blog/category/list_of_post_by_category.html'
    context = {'categories': categories, 'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)


def list_of_post(request):
    post = Post.objects.filter(status="published")
    template = 'blog/post/list_of_post.html'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)


def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    template = 'blog/post/post_detail.html'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absoulte_url(self):
        return reverse('blogCMSApp:list_of_post_by_category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Posts
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

def get_absoulte_url(self):
    return reverse('blogCMSApp:post_detail', args=[self.slug])

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for that pattern in `urls.py`, and then you need to build the correct URL for the post links:

```
url(
    r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 
    views.post_detail, 
    name='post_detail'
),
url(
    r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.list_of_post_by_category, 
    name='list_of_post_by_category'
),
```

And in the `Post` model:

```
def get_absoulte_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'blogCMSApp:post_detail', 
        args=[self.category.slug, self.slug]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works, however, big issue with this is, I can manually change the categorya to categoryb in the URL path and it will show the post, it should show 404. I can't figure out how to do a validation on this and where?

Comment: I suppose you changed `post_detail` to also accept a `category_slug` parameter. You can validate that `post.category.slug` is equal to that, otherwise raise `Http404`.

Comment: May I ask, for an example? Because i get error: First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'str'. When trying:  if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(post.category.slug, slug=category_slug)

Comment: Leave the `get_object_or_404` line as it was, just add afterwards `if post.category.slug != category_slug: raise Http404`.

Comment: Sorry, confused....this is what I have in my post_detail function in views.py:

def post_detail(request, category_slug,slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if post.category.slug != category_slug):
        raise Http404
    template = 'blog/post/post_detail.html'
    context = {'post': post, 'category':category}
    return render(request, template, context)

Comment: There's a `)` that shouldn't be there (my mistake in the previous comment, I deleted it).

Comment: Haha, I missed that as well :) Thanks, all working now.